# Understanding "LoadError: Unable to autoload constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see this question has been asked a bunch of times, but none of the solutions seem to be working.

I intermittently get this issue:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Directory::Apple::Listing, expected /my/path/lib/directory/apple/listing.rb
```

But the "expected" file is exactly the file that defines the constant?

```
## /my/path/lib/directory/apple/listing.rb

module Directory
  class Apple::Listing
    ...
  end
end
```

The lib folder is included in the `autoload_paths`:

```
# application.rb

config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

If I do a `spring stop` it will work for a while, but then I will inevitably see that annoying error again. What am I missing?

Comment: I've also tried defining the class as `class Directory::Apple::Listing`, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: The correct way is define the class is `module Directory; module Apple; class Listing; end; end; end`. Do not use the scope resolution operator (::) when defining classes/modules. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: So far so good! Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've tried this, and a million other things, and the error keeps coming back intermittently. The only solution ends up being to restart my server. It has also come up in our test pipeline as an intermittent error / "flaky spec". Sigh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Define (and reopen) namespaced classes and modules using explicit
>   nesting. Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising
>   constant lookups due to Ruby’s lexical scoping, which depends on the
>   module nesting at the point of definition.
>   - [The Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition)

```
# /lib/directory/apple/listing.rb
module Directory
  class Apple
    class Listing
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand the difference in the two declarations?

Comment: If you inspect the module nesting inside the class in this answer you will get `[Directory::Apple::Listing, Apple::Listing, Listing]`. In the original you would get `[Directory::Apple::Listing, Listing]` note that `Apple::Listing` is missing since you never reopened that module. That can lead to really suprising constant lookups. `class Apple::Listing` will also break unless the Apple module has already been defined. The old Rails classic autoloader would glaze over this since it monkeypatched `Module#constant_missing`.

Comment: Zeitwork does not since it actually uses `Module#autoload` instead of the old and hacky approach of the classic autoloader.

Comment: Thanks @max how do I inspect the module nesting inside the class? That makes it really clear!

Comment: `puts Module.nesting.inspect` its kind of strange since you're calling it on module but it will return the nesting where it is called.

Comment: Ran into this again when using a class method class << self. To fix it, I had to define the methods with self.method_name instead. Even though I followed your suggestion and the nesting was correct?

Comment: Its really hard to say anything definitive about the cause of that. Is it intermittent?